# custom splash screens not updating in phonegap build ios

Tags: ios, cordova, screen, splash-screen

here is my  Config.xml and also I have added splash screens in www/res/screen/ios as well as in /platforms/ios/project-name/Resources/splash
and the names of images are default but I have replaced the images and yes icons are changed but not able to change splash screen. it always displays default phonegap splash screen and then white screen and then my original application homepage.
another issue is that the icon is changing at one place only if I'll go to settings and search my app of zegr it gives default icon of phonegap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Zegr</name>

    <description>

Business Made Simple
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />   
   <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <!--
        Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
        <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
    -->

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" />

    <!-- Third party plugins -->
    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
    <!--
        <plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>
    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:

        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

    <access origin="*"/>
    <!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: Please guide me. I am stuck into this for 4-5 days. I am using phonegap version 5.5.0

Comment: You solve problem? I am stuck into this for more than 5 days too

Comment: yes solved it.
I skipped few sizes which is required

Comment: I solve this too yesterday. The problem was missing splash screens for device than I tested, iPad Retina. More details in portuguese: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152572/n%C3%A3o-carrega-o-splash-para-ios-no-phonegap-build/152710